# UART read consistently missing half of the transmitted bytes

Tags: microcontroller, uart, serial, atmel

I have setup a simple UART test on my SAML21 and believe I must be misusing the library due to the behavior I'm seeing

```
uint8_t testData[8] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06}

void broadcast_test_data(void)
{
    usart_write_buffer_wait(&usart_instance, testData, sizeof(testData))
}

void serial_data_handler(void)
{
    unit16_t rxInt;
    if (usart_read_wait(&usart_instance, &rxInt) == STATUS_OK) {
        printf("RX %d", rxInt);
    }
} 

int main(void)
{
    struct usart_config config_usart;
    usart_get_config_defaults(&config_usart);

    config_usart.baudrate = 1000;
    config_usart.mux_setting = USART_RX_3_TX_2_XCK_3;
    config_usart.pinmux_pad0 = PINMUX_UNUSED;
    config_usart.pinmux_pad1 = PINMUX_UNUSED;
    config_usart.pinmux_pad2 = PINMUX_PA24C_SERCOM3_PAD2;
    config_usart.pinmux_pad3 = PINMUX_PA24C_SERCOM3_PAD3;

    usart_enable(&usart_instance);

    while (1) {
        // run-loop
        SYSTEM_RunTasks();
        serial_data_handler();
    }
}
```

I verified that the TX data is transmitting the entire testData array via Putty.

The issue is that when I tie the RX and TX together to test receiving, I am only ever getting bytes (0x01, 0x02, and 0x06).  Is polling for RX data via the while loop not the way I should be doing this?  Do I need to somehow mark data as read before UART moves onto the next received byte?  Should I be asking for more than 1 byte at a time?

Thanks for any info you can provide

Comment: When you call usart_read_wait, right now if it returns an error you're just ignoring it. I would suggest changing your code to print out at least what error code you've gotten, if you don't get STATUS_OK. That might be informative. I'm not sure what could cause a problem like this but more data's always helpful.

Comment: How is `printf` implemented in your system? Does your UART library or hardware have a receive buffer for more than 1 byte?

Comment: http://asf.atmel.com/docs/latest/samd21/html/group__asfdoc__sam0__sercom__usart__group.html#gacffd0845249348d37d14c65a41132e41

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that both `usart_write_buffer_wait()` and `usart_read_wait()` are blocking. The USART hardware seems to have a 2 byte FIFO buffer on RX.

Now what happens is the RX FIFO is filled during writing, and `usart_write_buffer_wait` returns *during* the transmission of the *last* character.

As soon as `usart_read_wait` is called - which can only happen *after* `usart_write_buffer_wait` due to it being a blocking function, it reads the first 2 bytes from the fifo. The following bytes are missing due to fifo overflow - check hardware status registers, they should tell you that. 
The last byte is received and read once the usart finished the transmission's stop bit.

Workaround: Use interrupts or DMA for RX, TX or both.

Comment: Thank you, I added interrupts and it works great when I tie RX and TX together.  But when I connect to the transmitting device I never get an RX interrupt, is this something that the other device has to support?  Should I switch to DMA in this case?

Comment: Your baudrate is quite unusual. Perhaps it's a mismatch with the other side.

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting RX and TX to the same pin `PA24C`

```
config_usart.pinmux_pad2 = PINMUX_PA24C_SERCOM3_PAD2;
config_usart.pinmux_pad3 = PINMUX_PA24C_SERCOM3_PAD3;
```